# What is the difference between all the different types of learning within machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning, semi-supervised-learning

This is a question that is really hard to google, and the differences are confusing. Does anyone have good examples of the differences between them all?

- Supervised Learning
- Semi-Supervised Learning
- Distant Supervision
- Active Learning
- Lightly Supervised Learning
- Weakly Supervised Learning
- Competitive Learning
- Reinforcement Learning
- Unsupervised Learning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Supervised Learning**

In general, *supervised learning* refers to a situation in which you have some $X$ that is related to $y$, so that you can model how both are related (on average). In this case you can build a statistical model:

$$y = \beta X + u.$$

The model learns $\beta$, so that you are able to predict $y$ by: $\hat{y}=\hat{\beta}X$.

Examples are regression or classification tasks (e.g. using linear models, neural nets, boosting etc).

**Unsupervised Learning**

When you have only $X$ and no response $y$, you face an *unsupervised* problem. In this case, the focus is to identify patterns in $X$, e.g. by clustering. Examples for unsupervised learning are k-nearest neighbors (KNN) or principle components (PCA).

The book [Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/) provides a very good overview. Alternatively, the book [Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf) provides a more comprehensive overview.

**Reinforcement Learning**

Reinforcement learning is a little different. Here you try to find an optimal response to some problem, based on past experiance. Examples are self driving cars or a game of [tic tac toe](https://correlaid.org/blog/tic-tac-toe-ai/). So for every state of the environment (e.g. the state of the tic tac toe game), RF aims at finding an optimal response (best next move). Googles [DeepMind](https://www.deepmind.com/) and AlphaGo are RF-based. The book by [Sutton and Barto](https://web.stanford.edu/class/psych209/Readings/SuttonBartoIPRLBook2ndEd.pdf) is the standard literature here.